# Chi Square test- preparing the data in R

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

I am trying to prepare the data to run Chi-square test, but it returns the following: Error: all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite in fisher.test

Does anyone know what to do?

My dataset consists of seven species (4 animals per each species) and each species has 4 variables.

One part of the dataset looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("species1", "species1", "species2", "species2"),
             N1=c(28660, 37365, 29375, 29169), 
             N2=c(86872, 91519, 141865, 101298), 
             N3=c(140498, 51092, 93889, 42368), 
             N4=c(76942, 49351, 82002, 36730))
```

I am not sure how to prepare a data set in order to run chisq.test function?

Best!

Comment: What hypothesis do you want to test?

Comment: Your data seems to be numeric. The chisq.test is used to test categorical data.

Comment: I want to compare the effect of frequencies between the two models

Comment: Yes, it's numeric...these numbers are counts, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the "ID” column.

```
df <- data.frame(N1=c(28660, 37365, 29375, 29169), 
             N2=c(86872, 91519, 141865, 101298), 
             N3=c(140498, 51092, 93889, 42368), 
             N4=c(76942, 49351, 82002, 36730))
chisq.test(df)
```

you will get:

X-squared = 62305, df = 9, p-value < 2.2e-16

it depends on what hypothesis you want to test.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you very much! But I still don't understand why you tossed this column? And should I transform the data before running chisq.test because I get the same p value in each model which is not realistic?